# How many Apps can i use in one Django Project

Tags: django

i have a Django Project which i'm working on.
Now the Project gets bigger. I think there will be in the end approximately 40 Apps. I'm not sure if this is too much Apps for one Django project? Maybe one of you have some Experience with large Projects?
Thank you

Comment: There's not limit. What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: I have some doubt about speed of the project when it's get bigger. I Plan to integrate wagtail cms for blog and static sites in my project and also use the django admin for my internal stuff.

Comment: it's not speed, it's memory that gets used more with a larger project, as a lot of stuff gets loaded in memory when the app is loaded. Just monitor that.

Comment: So I have to take a server with lots of memory?

Comment: No, you have to watch the memory footprint of your app and determine memory based on that. My app uses 470MB of memory, so if I have a server with 2GB I can probably run 3-4 workers without affecting speed to much (more will start swapping).

Comment: So I have to cache my apps, templates or views?

Comment: Caching doesn't change the memory footprint of your app, but it offloads your workers since instead of being busy querying the db or getting files from disk or getting the request in the first place (so you need less workers for the same traffic load). Again, you don't need to do anything until you actually **measure** the memory footprint. If **one worker** becomes too large, then it's time to upgrade memory on your server. But otherwise, choose the number of workers based on the memory and if you need more, either give more memory to your server or use multiple servers.